# airflow DAG/Task stuck in running state

Tags: python, airflow

I am a newbie to airflow.

I have created an ETL pipeline and try to run it in DAG. However, it keeps running endlessly and cannot be finished.

I am running airflow in MacOS
Version of Airflow: 2.8.1

Here is my DAG code:

```
from datetime import timedelta
import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
import sqlite3

def hello_world():
    print("hello world")  

def get_played_track_etl_2():
    
    database_location = "sqlite:///my_played_track.db"
    load_dotenv()
    spotify_client_id = os.getenv('CLIENT_ID')
    spotify_client_secret = os.getenv('CLIENT_SECRET')
    redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:5000/callback'
    scope = "user-read-recently-played, user-read-private"

    sp_oauth = SpotifyOAuth(
        client_id=spotify_client_id,
        client_secret=spotify_client_secret,
        redirect_uri=redirect_uri,
        scope=scope,
        show_dialog=False
    )

    sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=sp_oauth)

    user_data = sp.current_user()
    print('My data:')
    print('Name:', user_data['display_name'])
    print('Followers:', user_data['followers']['total'])
    print('Link:', user_data['external_urls']['spotify'])
    print('Account:', user_data['product'])

    today = datetime.datetime.now()
    yesterday = today - timedelta(days=60)
    yesterday_unix_timestamp = int(yesterday.timestamp()) * 1000
    user_recent_play = sp.current_user_recently_played(limit=50,after=yesterday_unix_timestamp)

    song_name = []
    album_name = []
    album_url = []
    artist_name = []
    artist_genre = []
    artist_id = []
    artist_url = []
    artist_api_href = []
    played_at_list = []
    timestamp = []

    for song in user_recent_play['items']:
        song_name.append(song['track']['name'])
        album_name.append(song['track']['album']['name'])
        album_url.append(song['track']['album']['external_urls']['spotify'])
        artist_name.append(song['track']['album']['artists'][0]['name'])
        artist_id.append(song['track']['album']['artists'][0]['id'])
        artist_url.append(song['track']['album']['artists'][0]['external_urls']['spotify'])
        artist_api_href.append(song['track']['album']['artists'][0]['href'])
        played_at_list.append(song['played_at'])
        timestamp.append(song['played_at'][0:10])

    for id in artist_id:
        artist_info = sp.artist(artist_id=id)
        artist_genre.append(artist_info['genres'])

    song_dict = {
        'Song_name' : song_name,
        'album_name' : album_name,
        'album_url' : album_url,
        'artist_name' : artist_name,
        'artist_genre' : artist_genre,
        'artist_id' : artist_id,
        'artist_url' : artist_url,
        'artist_api_href' : artist_api_href,
        'played_at' : played_at_list,
        'timestamp' : timestamp
    }

    df_song = pd.DataFrame(
        data=song_dict,
        columns=song_dict.keys()
        )
    if not df_song.empty:
        df_song.artist_genre = df_song.artist_genre.str.join(',')
    print(df_song)
        
    # load
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(database_location)
    conn = sqlite3.connect('my_played_track.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    
    sql_query = """
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_played_track(
        song_name TEXT,
        album_name TEXT,
        album_url TEXT,
        artist_name TEXT,
        artist_genre TEXT,
        artist_id TEXT,
        artist_url TEXT,
        artist_api_href TEXT,
        played_at TEXT,
        timestamp TEXT,
        CONSTRAINT primary_key_constraint PRIMARY KEY (played_at)
    )
    """
    
    cursor.execute(sql_query)
    print("connect to database successfully")

    try:
        df_song.to_sql(
            "my_played_track", 
            con=conn, 
            index=False,
            if_exists='append')
    except:
        print("Data already exists in the database")
    
    conn.close()
    print("Disconnect database successfully")

default_args = {
    'owner' : 'airflow',
    'start_date' : days_ago(0,0,0,0,0),
    'email' : ['airflow@example.com'],
    'email_on_failure' : False,
    'email_on_retry' : False,
    'retries' : 1,
    'retry_delay' : timedelta(minutes=1),
}
    
dag = DAG(
    dag_id='spotify_dag',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='Our first DAG with ETL process.',
    schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1),
    catchup=False 
)

task_a = PythonOperator(
    task_id = 'a',
    python_callable=hello_world,
    dag=dag
)
    
run_etl = PythonOperator(
    task_id = 'whole_spotify_etl',
    python_callable=get_played_track_etl_2,
    dag=dag,  
)

task_a >> run_etl
```

Task_a works fine, but run_etl was running endlessly without any output.

[airflow task log page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXvym.png)

the function `get_played_track_etl_2` itself has no problem and can run without using airflow

Here is the Task Instance Details

```
Task Instance Details
Dependency  Reason
Task Instance Not Running   Task is in the running state
Task Instance State Task is in the 'running' state.
Task Instance Attributes
Attribute   Value
custom_operator_name    None
dag_model   <DAG: spotify_dag>
dag_run <DagRun spotify_dag @ 2024-02-28 00:00:00+00:00: scheduled__2024-02-28T00:00:00+00:00, state:running, queued_at: 2024-02-29 00:10:54.404092+00:00. externally triggered: False>
duration    None
end_date    None
execution_date  2024-02-28 00:00:00+00:00
executor_config {}
external_executor_id    None
hostname    corey.mynet
is_premature    False
is_trigger_log_context  False
job_id  65
map_index   -1
max_tries   1
metadata    MetaData()
next_kwargs None
next_method None
next_try_number 2
note    None
operator    PythonOperator
operator_name   PythonOperator
pid 80220
pool    default_pool
pool_slots  1
prev_attempted_tries    1
previous_start_date_success None
previous_ti None
previous_ti_success None
priority_weight 1
queue   default
queued_by_job   <airflow.jobs.job.Job object at 0x11a5562f0>
queued_by_job_id    57
queued_dttm 2024-02-29, 00:10:58
registry    <sqlalchemy.orm.decl_api.registry object at 0x1178fda50>
rendered_task_instance_fields   None
run_as_user None
run_id  scheduled__2024-02-28T00:00:00+00:00
start_date  2024-02-29, 00:11:01
state   running
stats_tags  {'dag_id': 'spotify_dag', 'task_id': 'whole_spotify_etl'}
task_id whole_spotify_etl
task_instance_note  None
test_mode   False
trigger_id  None
trigger_timeout None
try_number  1
unixname    corey
updated_at  2024-02-29, 00:11:01
Task Attributes
Attribute   Value
SERIALIZER_VERSION  1
dag_id  spotify_dag
depends_on_past False
deps    frozenset({<TIDep(Previous Dagrun State)>, <TIDep(Trigger Rule)>, <TIDep(Not In Retry Period)>, <TIDep(Not Previously Skipped)>})
do_xcom_push    True
downstream_task_ids ()
email   ['airflow@example.com']
email_on_failure    False
email_on_retry  False
end_date    None
execution_timeout   None
executor_config {}
extra_links []
ignore_first_depends_on_past    True
inlets  []
is_setup    False
is_teardown False
label   whole_spotify_etl
max_active_tis_per_dag  None
max_active_tis_per_dagrun   None
max_retry_delay None
on_execute_callback None
on_failure_callback None
on_failure_fail_dagrun  False
on_retry_callback   None
on_success_callback None
op_args []
op_kwargs   {}
operator_extra_links    ()
operator_name   PythonOperator
outlets []
output  {{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='whole_spotify_etl', dag_id='spotify_dag', key='return_value') }}
owner   airflow
params  {}
pool    default_pool
pool_slots  1
priority_weight 1
priority_weight_total   1
queue   default
resources   None
retries 1
retry_delay 0:01:00
retry_exponential_backoff   False
run_as_user None
shallow_copy_attrs  ()
sla None
start_date  2024-02-28 00:00:00+00:00
subdag  None
supports_lineage    False
task_id whole_spotify_etl
task_type   PythonOperator
template_ext    []
template_fields ['templates_dict', 'op_args', 'op_kwargs']
template_fields_renderers   {'templates_dict': 'json', 'op_args': 'py', 'op_kwargs': 'py'}
templates_dict  None
trigger_rule    all_success
ui_color    #ffefeb
ui_fgcolor  #000
upstream_task_ids   ('a',)
wait_for_downstream False
wait_for_past_depends_before_skipping   False
weight_rule downstream
```

[Task instance Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/visLn.png)

In the logs folder, I can find the log for the task "run_etl"

Here is the log for task "run_etl"

```
[2024-02-29T08:11:01.249+0800] {taskinstance.py:1956} INFO - Dependencies all met for dep_context=non-requeueable deps ti=<TaskInstance: spotify_dag.whole_spotify_etl scheduled__2024-02-28T00:00:00+00:00 [queued]>
[2024-02-29T08:11:01.253+0800] {taskinstance.py:1956} INFO - Dependencies all met for dep_context=requeueable deps ti=<TaskInstance: spotify_dag.whole_spotify_etl scheduled__2024-02-28T00:00:00+00:00 [queued]>
[2024-02-29T08:11:01.253+0800] {taskinstance.py:2170} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 2
[2024-02-29T08:11:01.262+0800] {taskinstance.py:2191} INFO - Executing <Task(PythonOperator): whole_spotify_etl> on 2024-02-28 00:00:00+00:00
[2024-02-29T08:11:01.268+0800] {standard_task_runner.py:60} INFO - Started process 80220 to run task
[2024-02-29T08:11:01.273+0800] {standard_task_runner.py:87} INFO - Running: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'spotify_dag', 'whole_spotify_etl', 'scheduled__2024-02-28T00:00:00+00:00', '--job-id', '65', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/spotify_dag.py', '--cfg-path', '/var/folders/y9/wh0jz8056576vp427n6d9rtw0000gn/T/tmpvxqd54p5']
[2024-02-29T08:11:01.275+0800] {standard_task_runner.py:88} INFO - Job 65: Subtask whole_spotify_etl
[2024-02-29T08:11:01.309+0800] {task_command.py:423} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: spotify_dag.whole_spotify_etl scheduled__2024-02-28T00:00:00+00:00 [running]> on host corey.mynet
[2024-02-29T08:11:01.345+0800] {taskinstance.py:2480} INFO - Exporting env vars: AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_EMAIL='airflow@example.com' AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_OWNER='airflow' AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID='spotify_dag' AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID='whole_spotify_etl' AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE='2024-02-28T00:00:00+00:00' AIRFLOW_CTX_TRY_NUMBER='1' AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID='scheduled__2024-02-28T00:00:00+00:00'
[2024-02-29T14:36:18.844+0800] {local_task_job_runner.py:302} WARNING - State of this instance has been externally set to None. Terminating instance.
[2024-02-29T14:36:18.870+0800] {process_utils.py:131} INFO - Sending Signals.SIGTERM to group 80220. PIDs of all processes in the group: [80220]
[2024-02-29T14:36:18.871+0800] {process_utils.py:86} INFO - Sending the signal Signals.SIGTERM to group 80220
[2024-02-29T14:37:18.901+0800] {process_utils.py:149} WARNING - process psutil.Process(pid=80220, name='Python', status='running', started='08:11:01') did not respond to SIGTERM. Trying SIGKILL
[2024-02-29T14:37:18.906+0800] {process_utils.py:86} INFO - Sending the signal Signals.SIGKILL to group 80220
[2024-02-29T14:37:18.914+0800] {process_utils.py:79} INFO - Process psutil.Process(pid=80220, name='Python', status='terminated', exitcode=<Negsignal.SIGKILL: -9>, started='08:11:01') (80220) terminated with exit code Negsignal.SIGKILL
[2024-02-29T14:37:18.915+0800] {standard_task_runner.py:175} ERROR - Job 65 was killed before it finished (likely due to running out of memory)
```

Question:
How can I run the task with airflow porperly?

It is expected that all the Tasks can run properly.

However, only task_a can run properly and task run_etl run endlessly with no output.

Also, the terminal keep popping out these messages

[Terminal log in vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMb9X.png)

Comment: are you running Airflow on docker or directly on macos.
To get some idea where your task is getting stuck : you can import logging and add logging.info("completed step xyz") statements at a few places in your run_etl task

Comment: @subram Hi, I am running Airflow directly on MacOS.
After adding some log in every lines of code, I found it stuck in 
-> user_data = sp.current_user()
However, I can be run without airflow :(

Comment: could be that those env variables you are using for auth are not getting picked up.

Comment: I found that the problem maybe occur at 
sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=sp_oauth) 
since I print sp.me() it did not output anything

Comment: @subram Finally I figured out the problem. This is related to MacOS and requests module bug-> https://bugs.python.org/issue28342

The solution is to add NO_PROXY="*" in .env as environment variable